# How to get access token with Xamarin.Auth?

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.auth

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth

So that website shows how to authenticate the user, and how to make requests, but it skips the step in between which is getting the access token out of the url. This is probably really simple but this is the first time I am working with API's. If someone could view that website and find out exactly how I am supposed **A.)** Find the url with the access token in it(I know the authentication link redirects you to it in a browser, but in Xamarin.Auth, after authenticating, you go straight back to the app instead of the redirect url. **B.)** to extract the access token out of the url. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck "Disable implicit OAuth" in your client's security settings on the Instagram site.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
               clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
               scope: "basic",
               authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"),
               redirectUrl: new Uri ("REDIRECT_URL"));

auth.AllowCancel = allowCancel;

// If authorization succeeds or is canceled, .Completed will be fired.
auth.Completed += (s, ee) => {
    var token = ee.Account.Properties ["access_token"];
};

var intent = auth.GetUI (this);
StartActivity (intent);
```

For other services you can just use OAuth2Request to execute your protected requests.